# How I access psql, createdb and other postgress commands from a launched postgres container in the parent host terminal?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm launching a [postgres Docker](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/postgres/#connect-to-it-from-an-application) container on a Mac with with:

`docker run --name cool-postgres -p 5433:5433 -e POSTGRES_USER=cooluser -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=securepassword -e POSTGRES_DB=cooldb --rm postgres`

Newer to Docker, my goal is to run `psql`, `createdb` and/or other related postgresql commands from terminal parent host after successfully launching the Docker instance, eventually writing to the database created above. How do I go about referencing the container in a way I can run its commands? Reading through the documentation, I'm not quite seeing a good solution. I may be able to run the psql command on launch it seems, but this will need to be done from a shell script.

Please let me know if I can provide additional information while troubleshooting connections.

Comment: Do you mean simply running a `docker exec` command? If you type `docker ps` and take the container's id, you can then run `docker exec -it <container_id> bash` to enter the container as a shell. From there you can run any commands you want

Comment: Aha. That's progress and I will dig deeper. My original thoughts were to:
`docker run ....`
then next line
`dropdb cooldb`
without an error about dropdb not being found. Maybe this isn't a good use case?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Are you trying to execute a command that would run everytime you up the container? If so you probably want to make a Dockerfile or use docker-compose to execute a script that runs commands for you at startup. Otherwise, would you mind re-explaining what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hmm, I've never worked eith CodeBuild unfortunately, but if the containers are on the same docker network, they'll be able to communicate with eachother. Are the commands in buildspec being run inside the container? If so, does the container have docker installed? If it's creating a container and running commands from the host to the container then you could create another container and run commands from the host as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I go about referencing the container in a way I can run its commands?

You don't.  The container has its own filesystem that's isolated from the host's.  The host can't run commands in the container (directly), the container can't run commands on the host, and containers can't run commands in other containers.

The usual way to do this is to install a client package on the host (on OSX with Homebrew, `brew install postgres`), `docker run` the server, and run the client commands against the server.  In this very specific case where you're running a command from a shell directly on the host against a container on that same host it's okay to use `localhost` as the `$PGHOST` value.